# Proof a curve for which all osculating planes go through the origin is planar

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Proof a (ALP) curve for which all osculating planes go through the origin is planar.

My approach: We write
$$0 = \alpha(s)+ a(s)\mathbf T(s) + b(s)\mathbf N(s)$$
Then
$$0=\mathbf{T}+a'\mathbf{T}+\kappa a\mathbf{N}+b'\mathbf{N}+b\mathbf{N}'$$
Using Frenet we conclude
$$0=(1+a'-\kappa b)\mathbf{T}+(\kappa a+b')\mathbf{N}+\tau b\mathbf{B}$$
So then we conclude that $\tau b=0$, however I don't see how we can conclude that $\tau=0$ from here. For let's say $b(s_0)=0$, then we would have that 
$$0 =\alpha(s_0)+ a(s_0)\mathbf T(s_0)$$
$$0=(1+a')\mathbf{T}+(\kappa a+b')\mathbf{N}$$
i.e. $a'(s_0)=-1$ and $\kappa a+b'=0$, neither of which seem contradictory to anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have the answer.

Your curve is differentiable, hence continuous. If $\tau(s_0)\neq 0$, then $\tau(s)\neq 0$, for $s$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $s_0$. Therefore, for $s\in U$, we have $b(s)=b'(s)=\kappa(s)a(s)=1+a'(s)=0$. We can then conclude that $\kappa(s)=0$, which means that the curve is on a straight line.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, I still don't see a contradiction? How does the curve locally being a line contradict anything?

Comment: Well, first of all, if $\kappa=0$ on an interval, then $\mathbf N,\mathbf B$ aren't even defined on that interval, so $\tau$ doesn't make sense. In order to speak of an osculating plane, you must first assume $\kappa\ne 0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, makes sense